# Sort entity and its nested collection @OneToMany Spring Data JPA with Pageable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sorting, jpa

Is there a way to sort an entity and its nested collection in a @OneToMany relationship with a Pageable interface?

I have these two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "course")
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    ....contructors, getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "review")
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String rating;

    @ManyToOne
    private Course course;

    ....contructors, getters and setters
}
```

This repository

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long> {
}
```

This service

```
@Service
public class CourseService {

    @Autowired
    CourseRepository courseRepository;

    public Page<Course> getCourses(Pageable pageable) {
        return courseRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

}
```

And this controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CourseController {

    @Autowired
    CourseService courseService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/courses", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Page<CourseDTO>> readInteractionsPagedParam(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Course> pageCourse = courseService.getCourses(pageable);
        ... To DTO and return it
    }
}
```

I found other similar questions but in the answers the sorting become static, like @OrderBy annotation but the need is that the sorting will be dynamic, I mean, I must order by any property in course and review. I must use Pagable too.

I need something like these but I tried them and only sort the entity Course, the entity Review never is sorted

```
.../api/courses?page=0&size=10&sort=name,asc&sort=reviews.rating,asc
.../api/courses?page=0&size=10&sort=name,asc&sort=reviews.rating,desc
.../api/courses?page=0&size=10&sort=name,desc&sort=reviews.rating,asc
.../api/courses?page=0&size=10&sort=name,desc&sort=reviews.rating,desc
```

I new in all of this, Java, Spring, JPA, Hibernate, etc and I would like to know if is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a dot "." between the parent and the nested property you want to sort upon.

eg: course.something